# Indent n rows n times

Tags: vim, indentation

I am trying to indent several rows several times in Vim and could not figure out if there is a "direct" way to tell Vim to do so. For example, how do I indent 5 rows 5 indentation levels? I could of course do `5>>....` or `Ctrl-V`, mark 5 rows and then do `5>`. But I was looking for something more like `5>5>`, but that indents 25 lines one level instead.

Comment: Note that often when you want to do this type of operation, it's in the context of "I want to fix the indent level of this code".  If that's what you're actually trying to do, then be aware that vim supports that operation directly for a lot of programming languages:  just `=iB` to fix the indenting of all lines within the current block, without having to count how many lines there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine block selection with what you're already doing i.e.

`V5j5>`

Which would select 5 rows down and indent the selected block 5 steps.

Comment: Note that `V` is not necessary, `v` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
:>>>>>5
```

is another way.

```
vip5>
```

could solve your problem, too, if applicable.

And another slightly less practical (but very precise) one:

```
:,5le20
```

where `20` is the exact number of spaces (or tabs and spaces if `:set noexpandtab`) you want.

Comment: I just +1 yours, and remove mine.. :) now this answer has my power too !! hohoho..

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing this - you can make a macro to do that for you.

for example, to save a macro under key `a`, type following :

```
qaV5j5>q
```

`q` stands for starting/stopping typing onto register.
then, if you type `@a` macro from register `a` will be executed and your 5 lines will be indented 5 times. every repeated usage of last macro can be executed by `@@`.

if that helped, please check http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros

Comment: That's a step closer, I would have no problems at all finding a 'custom' solution for this. My problem is that it might be 5 lines 5 levels, but it might as well be 20 lines 3 levels. Maybe I have to resort to a custom built function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this      : `:1,5s/^/     /`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sure, that works, but that's even more time-consuming than using one of my forementioned commands. That's a useful tip however, I did not know that you could specify the row range for the substitute command!